# Viewport inside iFrame ignored

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari

I have a page for phone-devices with a width of 640px. Because I am going to use this in a fb-app I have it wrapped in an iframe with a width of 810px.

The problem is that no matter how I change the viewport-settings it never gets applied when browsing in the iframe. Accessing the page for phone-devices directly displays perfectly, but I somehow can't get the content to stretch the 810px of the iframe.

I can't make a working jsfiddle for this, but I have a case here: http://optimuscrime.net/display.html

The `display.html`-file simply has a

```
<iframe src="viewframe.html" style="width: 810px; height: 1200px;"></iframe>
```

`viewframe.html` has all it's content based on a width of 640px and a viewport-setting like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640, initial-scale=1">
```

Before all the "show us what you've tried"-cries: I've tried every single combination of width, initial scale etc. The problem is that the content inside the iframe never gets affected by the viewport-settings.

Comment: Given that it's now five years later, I'm hoping you might have found a solution to this... I'm having the exact same issue! Anything you can share?

Comment: @MattLacey No, I am afraid I never got this to work. I redid the site to be responsive instead. That way the rendered viewport width became irrelevant.

Comment: Damn. I have my iframe scaling with the device which is great, but I can't make the content in there work the way it does if it's rendered directly in browser and leverages the view port meta tag.